# Unable to create process using ... Python

Tags: python, pip

My python is not working, i didn't change anything in configs or files, basically my PyCharm broken by himself.

Simple code:

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
import pyautogui as py

print(py.position())
```

I tried `pip install pyautogui` just for test `pip` and this return:

```
Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\Gabri\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe
C:/Users/Gabri/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/Prática/Vamove/qlqrcoisa.py'
```

I did same command in `cmd` and print this:

```
The specified disk or floppy disk cannot be accessed.
```

I also tried `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` and same return

> In morning was working normally, but now i don't understand how it's broken

> I use `Python3.9`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just add my path of python 3.9

`C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0`

to `Environment variables` and restarted my pc